# Laravel schedule run for some command is long

Tags: laravel, kernel, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I want to know how does work running commands from Kernel on production? If every command has to be executed everyminute and some command needs time to do everything and last up to an hour, should other commands wait this to be finished or others commands will be executed normally every minute??

Comment: If a job should be executed every minute and it takes an hour to do so, you’re doing something very wrong.

Comment: @dbf I have to update thousands data on external API, so I have to go through all data in  my database and make update for every of them, is there any other way to solve this..because updating so many data can take time

Comment: One command is one process. It is executed regardless of the completion of the previous command on scheduling.

Comment: you can try to limit each of the large process , make it small chunk of it , and than send it to another queue in different connection , read <a href="https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#connections-vs-queues">here</a> for more info

Comment: @milica98 You can assume most problems have been solved one way or the other. It's mostly a compromise between the work need, the amount of computation at hand the time (resources) available. If you process "large" amount of data, down-scale the "large" into "small", try to make groups of data that can be send either independently from each other or create a dependency list what sequence it should follow. Caching would help and up-front design, meaning those systems (db, compiler, etc) should solve the problems they were designed for, e.g. SQL can process things much faster than PHP can, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this section on Queues. You are able to schedule your Jobs exactly as you wish.

[Link here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#connections-vs-queues)

Comment: I have to update thousands data on external API, so I have to go through all data in my database and make update for every of them, is there any other way to solve this..because updating so many data can take time

Comment: So, a similar scenario we had, we had to create a job that ran the queries on all the data on the database. This was only a one-time operation for the initial dataset. After that, we wrote a script that would perform the functions we wanted and that would update the database accordingly as new information came.

Comment: So, in some instances, for your initial dataset, you might have no option but to run the long queries and fix that as you go.